# Can lightning:navigation be used in Communities

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-community, navigation

I am trying to implement a navigation mechanism for my community

So I am trying to implement the new [lightning:navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation) component.

This is my component - `main`:

**MARKUP**

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:appHostable,lightning:isUrlAddressable">
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
    <lightning:button variant="base" label="Open page" title="Click to open page with queryString attributes" onclick="{!c.handleClick}"/>
</aura:component>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
({
    openPage: function(component, event, helper) {
        var pageReference = {
            type: 'standard__component',
            attributes: {
                'componentName': 'c__main'
            },
            state: {
                type: 'open',
                id: 'a1ZW0000001Pc95MAC'
            }
        };
        var navService = component.find("navService");
        navService.navigate(pageReference);
    }
})
```

When I add this component to lightning experience from the app builder, the navigation happens good and I get the url of the component + the 2 attributes of the queryString.

But when I add this component in my community - a click on the button does not do anything.

**QUESTION**

Is `lightning:navigation` supported in Salesforce Communities?

If it is - what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

lightning:navigation is not supported in communities .Take a look at Summer18 release notes [here](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_lc_components_navigation.htm) that clearly mentions below

> These resources aren’t supported in other containers, such as Lightning Components for Visualforce, Lightning Out, or Communities. This is true even if you access these containers inside Lightning Experience or the Salesforce mobile app.

Update:

With Recent releases it is now supported in lightning communities as well .

Comment: Darn, do you know if it is going to be supported in the near future?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Do you want to navigate between two components in same page or different ? If different then use the https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/forceCommunity:routeLink/documentation link else you might need to build your own .Not sure on its future roadmap .Thanks

Comment: My whole community is developed with lightning components, also the top ruler. I want to stay on the same page if the page refreshes, and also to easily go to different pages with the querystring

Comment: For different page use forcecommunity:routelink that works .Also releber you can use navigateTourl and navigateToObject events and pass parameters

Comment: forcecommunity:routelink is for pages automatically generated from the provided record ID, and that is not good for me. Would force:navigateToURL work? if so do you know how do I get params from quesryString?

Comment: Old school way of using window object and regex !! Yes navigateatoURL will work for sure

Comment: You should be able to pass parameters as well

Comment: I can confirm, **navigateToURL still works in communities** and you can always create a new page in Communities containing your lightning component and then navigate to that page url. It's just hard to know if it's deprecated or not since at the moment I couldn't find it in the component library.

Comment: navigateToComponent() is what that will be depreciated .navigateToURL wont be .

Comment: @MohithShrivastava do you have a reference where they said lightning:navigation standard__component is enabled for communities. We couldn't find any article in the release notes. and it is not documented in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm).

Answer (score 4):

There's been an update for this since the best answer was posted and it's now possible to navigate around at your heart's content.

Here's how:

On the component:

```
<!-- exampleComponent.cmp -->
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>
    <!-- Your content here -->
    <lightning:button label="Navigate To Page" variant="Neutral" onclick="{!c.completeOrder}" />
</aura:component>
```

In the controller:

```
({
    navToPage : function (component, event, helper) {
        // gets the <lightning:navigation> tag on the component
        let navService = component.find("navService");

        // Sets the route to [Org url]/[Community uri]/[pageName]
        let pageReference = {
            type: "comm__namedPage", // community page. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm
            attributes: {
                pageName: 'home' // pageName must be lower case
            }
        }

        navService.navigate(pageReference);
    }
})
```

### And that's it!

If you'd prefer, there are more options including generating the url on init and saving it in an attribute to use later, or writing the controller code in the helper file instead of directly in the controller, which allows you to more cleanly input a pageName without a giant chunk of code - especially if you want to reuse it.

For more info, see the below links:

lightning:navigation tag:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation

Page Reference Types:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm

Cheers Guys! Happy coding!

Dunks

Comment: Thanks @Dunks184 this is very good to know

Comment: Do you happen to know which API this was implemented in?

Comment: Hi @SteveSchrab, I wasn't able to tag you from my phone the other day so here's the answer again:

Hi Steve, I'm pretty sure it was API version 47.0. I think there had just been a release recently when I posted it and we had updated our api version, but I don't think I needed to update the community version. I can't quite remember. Which api version are you hoping to use?