# Why Salesforce doesn't provide router for Lightning Component(LWC, Aura)?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning-web-components

Why Salesforce doesn't provide router for Lightning Component(LWC, Aura)? How can I implement when I want route within Salesforce org and Lightning community?

Comment: ...along the lines of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/270415/how-to-handle-multiple-step-forms-in-community . [This](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227027/can-lightningnavigation-be-used-in-communities) answer also has a good example of a simple router

Answer (score 1):

***Salesforce doesn't provide a built-in router for Lightning Components (both Aura and Lightning Web Components) similar to what is available in some other web frameworks.***

However, you can implement your own routing mechanism using various approaches.

Here's a general guide on how to implement routing within Salesforce org and Lightning communities:

#### Using Navigation Mixin (LWC):

Lightning Web Components have a Navigation Mixin that you can use to navigate to other Lightning components or pages. Here's a basic example:

1. **Import NavigationMixin:**

   ```js
   import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
   import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
   ```
2. **Extend your component with NavigationMixin:**

   ```js
   export default class YourComponent extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
       // Your component logic here
   }
   ```
3. **Navigate to Another Page:**

   ```js
   this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
       type: 'standard__recordPage',
       attributes: {
           recordId: 'recordId',
           objectApiName: 'objectApiName',
           actionName: 'view'
       }
   });
   ```

#### Using Lightning Events (Aura):

In Aura components, you can use Lightning Events to communicate between components and simulate a form of routing:

1. **Fire an Event to Signal Navigation:**

   ```js
   // In the component firing the event
   var navigateEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
   navigateEvent.setParams({
       componentDef: "c:YourComponent",
       componentAttributes: {
           // Your component attributes here
       }
   });
   navigateEvent.fire();
   ```
2. **Handle the Event in the Target Component:**

   ```js
   // In the target component
   <aura:handler event="force:navigateToComponent" action="{!c.handleNavigationEvent}" />

   // In the controller
   handleNavigationEvent: function(component, event, helper) {
       var targetCmp = event.getParam("componentDef");
       var attributes = event.getParam("componentAttributes");

       // Handle navigation and pass attributes as needed
   }
   ```